# Check values in Array via VBA Dictionary

Tags: vba, dictionary, variables

I am trying to store an array of unique string values from a certain column. However I can't seem to be able to access the values in the array while the code is running. Would you be able to tell me what additional line of code would I need, to check what is being stored in the array when it is in fact running, and eventually copy those unique values to another sheet? Code below:

Find unique values in Column END DATE so to check whether multiple dates need to be imported:

```
Sub Find_Unique_Values()     
Dim PaceData(), UniqueValues As Variant, r As Long

With PaceDataSheet

PaceData = .UsedRange.value

Set UniqueValues = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For r = 2 To UBound(PaceData)
    UniqueValues(PaceData(r, datecolumn.Column)) = Empty

Next r

End With

End Sub
```

Any help is super appreciated. Thanks very much!

Comment: What is `datecolumn`? How is it declared? How is it assigned?

Comment: @Vityata Apologies for not expressing that earlier. Datecolumn is public defined range, declared as: datecolumn = .UsedRange.Find("END DATE", , xlValues, xlWhole). It is in this column that I'd like to find the unique values  mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*However I can't seem to be able to access the values in the array while the code is running.* - here is a way to do this easily, using `.UsedRange`, as in your code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim PaceData As Variant
    Dim someRange As Range

    Set someRange = Worksheets(1).UsedRange 'A1:C10
    PaceData = someRange

    Dim myRows As Long: myRows = someRange.Rows.Count
    Dim myCol As Long: myCol = someRange.Columns.Count

    Dim cnt1 As Long
    Dim cnt2 As Long

    For cnt1 = 1 To myRows
        For cnt2 = 1 To myCol
            Debug.Print PaceData(cnt1, cnt2)
        Next cnt2
    Next cnt1

End Sub
```

The `UsedRange` is "translated" as a 2-dimensional array like this:

[image]

and knowing the `Rows.Count` and the `Columns.Count` of the passed range, we get the dimensions.